# named_scope to order posts by last comment date

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, named-scope

Posts has_many Comments

I'm using [searchlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/searchlogic) which will order by named scopes.  So, I'd like a named scope that orders by each post's most recent comment.

```
named_scope :ascend_by_comment, :order => ...comments.created_at??...
```

I'm not sure how to do a `:joins` and get only the most recent comment and sort by its `created_at` field, all in a `named_scope`.

I'm using mysql, fyi.

**EDIT:**

This is the SQL query I'd be trying to emulate:

```
SELECT tickets.*, comments.created_at AS comment_created_at FROM tickets 
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT comments.ticket_id, MAX(comments.created_at) AS created_at 
  FROM comments group by ticket_id) comments 
ON tickets.id = comments.ticket_id ORDER BY comment_created_at DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
named_scope :ascend_by_comment,
  :joins => "LEFT JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id",
  :group => "id",
  :select => "posts.*, max(comments.created_at) AS comment_created_max",
  :order => "comment_created_max ASC"
```

You can try to optimize it, but it should work and give you some hints how to do it.

*Edit*:

After you edited question and shown that you want inner join (no posts without comments?), you can of course change `:joins => "..."` with `:joins => :comments`.

Comment: I was going for the simplest case. I figured I could switch to a LEFT JOIN after I got one working with INNER JOIN.  Also, this is for a helpdesk and every "post" has an initial "comment" so I'm okay with using INNER JOIN in this case.

Comment: I added `:group => "posts.id"` for clarity in case I/anyone else wants to pull in the commment.id as well.  Works perfectly with searchlogic and will_paginate.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by joining or including the associated model through the scope, something like this will do the trick:

`named_scope :ascend_by_comment, :joins => :comments, :order => "comments.created_at DESC"`

Comment: Multiple comments with an INNER JOIN will give duplicate posts, though.  It's selecting ALL comments and the associated post.

Comment: According to this ticket ( http://bit.ly/75FrSi ) named_scopes should not be returning a single object. It's scoping, not a finder, also they suggest to use, in this case, `ascend_by_comment.first` to return only 1 record instead of all, Hope you find it useful!

Comment: I don't want my named scope to return one Post.  I want it order the posts by their last comment.  This named_scope would live in the Post model, not the Comment model (at least, that's how I think it should work.)  So, I need to lookup one and only one comment per post, specifically the latest one.